# Splitting Full Name

Tags: java, string

I have string for instance, "John Daws Black" splitted with spaces and I need to split them to two parts so that there will be name part like "John Daws" and surname part like "Black". However the front name part can be any length like "John Erich Daws Black". My code can get the last part:

```
public String getSurname(String fullName){
    String part = "";
     for (String retval: fullName.split(" "))
         part = retval;
         return part;
}
```

But I don't know how to get the front part.

Comment: Split the string like you're doing, reverse the string, take the first element in that reversed array which is your last name. After that, the rest can be the first name since it seems like middle name is not a concern.

Comment: @Habil Ganbaril If the name is "John Erich Daws Black", what is expected from you?

Comment: What about Giovani dos Santos?

Comment: Do you care if the person is "Dick Van Dyke", where the surname is two words? There is no algorithmic way to always divide up a name.

Comment: @user3437460 Since that is only slightly different from given example, it would be two strings: `"John Erich Daws"` and `"Black"`

Comment: I needed to get the front part like name without last surname word.Thank u all again :)

Comment: Or [mononymous people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person#Modern_times)?

Comment: @HabilGanbarli I see, basically you just want to "remove" the last word no matter what (as long as there are more than 1 word).

Comment: There really isn't an efficient way to handle edge cases... Consider `Mr. John Erich Daws Black  III`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just find the *last* space, then manually split there using `substring()`.

```
String fullName = "John Erich Daws Black";
int idx = fullName.lastIndexOf(' ');
if (idx == -1)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only a single name: " + fullName);
String firstName = fullName.substring(0, idx);
String lastName  = fullName.substring(idx + 1);
```

Comment: Thank u very much :)

Comment: Good Answer Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
public String getName(String fullName){
    return fullName.split(" (?!.* )")[0];
}

public String getSurname(String fullName){
    return fullName.split(" (?!.* )")[1];
}
```

Comment: A simple `lastIndexOf(' ')` would be much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Below methods worked for me. It takes into account that if middle name is present, then that gets included in first name:

```
private static String getFirstName(String fullName) {
        int index = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
        if (index > -1) {
            return fullName.substring(0, index);
        }
        return fullName;
    }

    private static String getLastName(String fullName) {
        int index = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
        if (index > -1) {
            return fullName.substring(index + 1 , fullName.length());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the last element of the array after spliting it:

```
    String fullName= "John Daws Black";
    String surName=fullName.split(" ")[fullName.split(" ").length-1];
    System.out.println(surName);
```

Output:

```
Black
```

**Edit:**
for the front part, use substring:

```
    String fullName= "John Daws Black";
    String surName=fullName.split(" ")[fullName.split(" ").length-1];
    String firstName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.length() - surName.length());
    System.out.println(firstName );
```

Output:

```
John Daws
```

Comment: Not an answer to the real problem stated as *"But I don't know how to get the front part"*.

Comment: Thank u but i just needed to get the front part

Comment: Messed up the `surName` part. Should not be `[0]`.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right, I was in hurry while trying to correct my answer, answer edited again, thanks

Comment: Good, down-vote removed. I'm afraid I cannot endorse this answer with my up-vote, even though it produces the right result, because it is about the second-most inefficient way to get those results. The now-deleted answer that was building the first name by using `String = String + String` in a loop does however win the price for most inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Split all data by any size whitespace 
final Pattern whiteSpacePattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
final List<String> splitData = whiteSpacePattern.splitAsStream(inputData)
.collect(Collectors.toList());

//Create output where first part is everything but the last element
if(splitData.size() > 1){
    final int lastElementIndex = splitData.size() - 1;
    //connect all names excluding the last one
    final String firstPart = IntStream.range(0,lastElementIndex).
    .mapToObj(splitData::get)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    final String result = String.join(" ",firstPart,
    splitData.get(lastElementIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a re-write for **Andreas** answer above but using sperate methods to get first and last name

```
    public static String get_first_name(String full_name)
    {
      int last_space_index = full_name.lastIndexOf(' ');
      if (last_space_index == -1) // single name
          return full_name;
      else
          return full_name.substring(0, last_space_index);
    }

    public static String get_last_name(String full_name)
    {
      int last_space_index = full_name.lastIndexOf(' ');
      if (last_space_index == -1) // single name
          return null;
      else
          return full_name.substring(last_space_index + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I've used before that accounts for suffixes too.. ( 3 chars at the end )

```
/**
 * Get First and Last Name : Convenience Method to Extract the First and Last Name.
 *
 * @param fullName
 *
 * @return Map with the first and last names.
 */
public static Map<String, String> getFirstAndLastName(String fullName) {

    Map<String, String> firstAndLastName = new HashMap<>();

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fullName)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Name Cannot Be Empty.");
    }

    String[] nameParts = fullName.trim().split(" ");

    /*
     * Remove Name Suffixes.
     */
    if (nameParts.length > 2 && nameParts[nameParts.length - 1].length() <= 3) {
        nameParts = Arrays.copyOf(nameParts, nameParts.length - 1);
    }

    if (nameParts.length == 2) {
        firstAndLastName.put("firstName", nameParts[0]);
        firstAndLastName.put("lastName", nameParts[1]);
    }

    if (nameParts.length > 2) {
        firstAndLastName.put("firstName", nameParts[0]);
        firstAndLastName.put("lastName", nameParts[nameParts.length - 1]);
    }

    return firstAndLastName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String[] name = fullname.split(" ")
if(name.size > 1){
    surName = name[name.length - 1]
    for (element=0; element<(name.length - 1); element++){
        if (element == (name.length - 1)) 
            firstName = firstName+name[element]
        else 
            firstName = firstName+name[element]+" "
    }
}
else 
    firstName = name[0]
```